# Как обрезать фон по дочерним элементам в css?

Tags: css, svg

background-clip видимо так не может

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

По шагам:

*#1. Квадрат с градиентом:*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid gray;" ><defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg">
     <stop offset="0"  stop-color="#C129BB" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F87045" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" />
</svg>
```

*#2. Дочерние элементы - белые квадраты сверху*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid gray;" ><defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg">
     <stop offset="0"  stop-color="#C129BB" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F87045" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" />
    <rect x="40" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
     <rect x="160" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
       <rect x="280" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
</svg>
```

*#3. Применение маски*

Дочерние элементы (белые прямоугольники) используются в качестве маски. При `fill="white"` для элементов маски, всё, что находится вне маски будет обрезано. В этом случае маска работает как `clipPath`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid gray;" >
    
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="Lg">
         <stop offset="0"  stop-color="#C129BB" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F87045" />
        </linearGradient>
      <mask id="msk">
         <rect x="40" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
            <rect x="160" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
              <rect x="280" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
      </mask>
</defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" mask="url(#msk)" />
</svg>
```

*#4. Вариант решения с **clipPath***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid gray;" >
    
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="Lg">
     <stop offset="0"  stop-color="#C129BB" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F87045" />
    </linearGradient>
      <clipPath id="clip">
     
         <rect x="40" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
     <rect x="160" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
       <rect x="280" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="white" /> 
      </clipPath>
</defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: а если это блоки в flex элементе с разной высотой?

Comment: @Artyom Блоки выступают в роли маски или clip-path для обрезки родительского блока, поэтому без разницы их размер и местоположение

Comment: @Artyom Я смотрю, вы не приняли ответ. Значит, что-то не устраивает, не подходит для вашей вёрстки.   Добавьте вариант вёрстки, которую вы хотите получить. Будем искать решение, которое вас устроит.

Comment: в svg у блоков по которым обрезается фиксированные размеры, у меня размер блоков заранее не известен т.к. это обычный html с текстом, мне подошел вариант с backgroud-attachment:fixed

Answer (score 1):

не может, да.
можно обрезать сам элемент  с помощью `clip-path` или SVG-маски. h t t p://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/